# UCanAccess Reference File deletion causes FileReading to break on my application

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, ucanaccess

This is a very weird error that I discovered when I tried to delete these "reference files" that ucanaccess creates.

First off what are they, and why do we need them?  Why are they created each time I try to create a db link and saved into the area where I am selecting my file?

Next I am basically using a filechooser to select a file, parse it, and then save it to an output stream.  At one point I have to access my DB using UCanAccess and also save some data to the output stream.

Basically the file is beign read using a custom library that was designed to read VB Binary Files and output them into Java.

Normally the files would parse through, and then it would catch an error at the point I was trying to access the db (since I'm working on it).  After having about 10 reference files, I deleted them and then got this error below.

```
Oct 09, 2014 3:25:21 PM Miscs.MessageLogger inform
INFO: Reading field 'Version'
Oct 09, 2014 3:25:21 PM Miscs.MessageLogger stop
SEVERE: EOF encounter while reading field 'Version'
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1274370218.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1759)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: Miscs.ParsingException: EOF encounter while reading field 'Version'
    at Miscs.MessageLogger.stop(MessageLogger.java:39)
    at Communications.VB6Binary.deserialize(VB6Binary.java:261)
    at binaryc.PlanHead.<init>(PlanHead.java:67)
    at uploader.AdminControl.upload(AdminControl.java:622)
    ... 57 more
```

Why is UCanAccess' reference files messing with this other library's read, and again why are these reference files needed? I'm going to look for a way to get rid of them, but it's annoying that I am having this weird error.  I have contacted the creator of the library as well to hear his thoughts.

Thank you all.

EDIT:  When I try restoring the files from the recycling bin I still get the error, even when I move the file to another folder.  I will have to see if the file was affected but this is very very very odd....

EDIT 2:  I realized in my code I was creating a new file, which was deleting the old one, but what's with this reference file, and why did it still allow my deleted file to be read...  Very very weird....

Comment: Firstly, you  never contacted me.
Secondly,  your error description is "weird" as well: that isn't odd, your pc seems to be possessed.
Anyway, a good description should include the jdbc url parameters you're using. 
Are you using memory=false?(that could explane a file generation, not your error).
Are you using lockmdb=true?
If not, "those reference files" are not created by ucanaccess.

Comment: I don't know who you are, the owner of UCanAccess?

Anyways, these reference files are surely created by UcanAccess, as the name is right in the file...

Folder name Ucanaccess_net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference@11ba4bc8

within the folder 83c1a6c3-8fad-4f89-a8a4-a2f40d15a6a8net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference@11ba4bc8.data

.log,.properties.script.... etc

I am using memeory=false, I'm niot using lockmdb, I'm decently new to DBs so I don't know "exactly" what I should be doing.

As for this error in the update 2 I mentioned I fixed it, but I still don't know why the references kept the files working

Comment: Also not too sure why someone downvoted me :(.....




---------

So you're saying the memory=false is what could cause the folder generation?

I heard that we should use that for production use or something, I just want to make sure I'm correct in what I'm doing.

If you would like some code I will edit the OP for you.

Thank you for your time....

Comment: I'm the author (I don't think "owner" is correct in this case).
Let me say, your question seemed to me a bit alarmist, but  maybe I didn't understand
Did someone downvote you? Please, don't cry.
I hope my answer below will be helpful. If not, please reply again, it would be great if  this point were clear.

Comment: Gotcha, and sorry for sounding rude I tried to edit how I asked that, but the 5 min edit just ended :(.

I wasn't sure if you were my buddy with the vb binary reader because I DID contact him as well lol.

I was scared, yes, I had no idea what was going on, but as the edits came I figured out that it wasn't UCanAccess "fault" but UCanAccess is definitely doing something weird.

Someone did downvote me, yes lol :(....  Some people are just rude....

Thanks for all of the help, I appreciate your time.  Next time I will goto uCanAccess page directly and try to contact you.

Answer (score 0):

UCanAccess uses hsqldb as mirror database.
Once the data are loaded in the mirror database, UCanAccess keeps always aligned the mirror database  and the mdb/accdb data.
When you're not executing a insert, delete or update but you're simply reading data, UCanAccess might access just to the mirror database.
Therefore the mentioned reference files are the files of a temporary hsqldb database, and they are created with memory=false. These files will be deleted at the VM process end.

You should choose  memory=false while dealing with large databases and when you can't set the max heap size (Xmx) needed. In other words you should do some consideration about the risk of an out of memory error, but most of the mdb/accdb(about 99%) are personal databases that could be loaded in memory without any risk. With memory=true(default) obviously UCanAccess is much faster, and you won't see any "weird" reference file. See also, in the UCanAccess web site, if SingleConnection parameter, useful for a memory usage optimisation in one-shot procedures, could fit your specific requirements (and use the latest 2.9.0.2 which has some further memory usage optimisations).

Anyway, to delete the reference files  (while hsqldb and so the VM process is accessing to them?), obviously causes a UCanAccess crash.
What you did after having deleted the reference files, is still unclear to me.
But maybe, now, it isn't so meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

I am basically using UCanAccess as a driver so I can connect to user's DB's, grab some data from their DB (like 2 fields but could be selecting multiple fields).

Some DBs MIGHT be big, some not, it's the user that is using them, but we aren't using the full db, just grabbing some data and that is all.

After the application is shut down, it is still running (but this might be due to the fact JavaFX for some reason still runs even after being shut down[old error] so I need to see about overriding @STOP.

Do you have a recommended heap size that would be safe for these use

Comment: Users might have 10k entries in a DB, so who knows....

I rather not leave behind reference files but the users might not notice3 them since it's in the application's folder.


What is the "Single connection" parameter?



The thing was that it wasn't crashing UCanAccess.

Basically I had this file that I was reading, and the reference file for some reason kept information about that File  even though my application was remaking the file(by accident).  The file was empty, still could get data into my application with that reference.  Delete the reference, and my application couldn't read it.

Comment: Memory usage mainly depends on data size and indexes size(the row number isn't important but the size of data in each row, yet 10k  isn't so much...) In general, in your case, it isn't easy estimate the heap space will be used, yet you can do some empirical assumption, based on the Xmx and the database file size: e.g., with -Xmx512m(if they aren't already used by other application components) you'll be surely able to open a 30-40 mb sized databases. In your assumptions, keep in consideration that your GUI application itself drinks a part of the available memory (but you can measure this part).

Comment: Yes, it looks like the singleconnection parameter is good for you:
once the one  connection to one database will be closed, the memory will be immediately recovered (with memory=true) because no data cache is needed to speed the time to establish the following connections . If memory=false instead, reference files will be deleted at the connection closing(I know you'll be glad of this).

Comment: Thank you... I will inquire into the sizes of the dbs to see what a good fit would be.

I specify .-xmx215m within the vm options of Netbeans (the IDE I'm using) and that is all I need to include it in my application?

My application is tiny, it's just a small application used to upload files to my server.
Speaking of that I was curious about using "UcanAccess" with a web application, is there any issues with it?  (Never worked with DB Connections on the web, but whwen I looked it up it seemed that using the web with access was different from JDBC or w/e).

Comment: I will look at the SingleConnection parameter, do you have an example, or somewhere I should look towards (I will go try to find it myself).

I just need to connect to one at a time, then I will move on.

For some reason the reference files persist even after my application is closed, so I'm not sure if I am not closing something properly, but I am closing my entitymanager


The db's shouldn't be too big, I was told 25-30mbs prob, but maybe I should set the xnx to 1024 instead?

I'm not sure if there is a problem with specifying too much heap, but what if there wasn't enough heap space?

Comment: If you specified too much heap for your system, your vm wouldn't start. It's a good practice to specify the Xms besides the Xmx(it might equal the Xmx). Reference files are surely deleted if connection.close is called on the only one active UCanAccess connection. But if there is another one connection active,(e.g. connection pool), or connection.close isn't truly called on the UCanAccess connection (e.g. connection pool), that won't happen.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.  Will look into specifying them.

I basically use a persistence progamatically, so I've been hearing that I'm not connecting to a pool, but rather directly.

 Map properties = new HashMap();
                

                
                // Configure the internal EclipseLink connection pool
                properties.put(TRANSACTION_TYPE, PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL.name());
                properties.put(JDBC_DRIVER, "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                properties.put(JDBC_URL, "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + db + ";memory=false");

Comment: properties.put(JDBC_USER, "");
                properties.put(JDBC_PASSWORD, "");
              //  properties.put( "provider" , "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider");
                
                
                emf2 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AccessPU", properties);
                em2 = emf2.createEntityManager();    

I have been told that this method isn't very good for production and such, but I am at a deadline and have to get this product out, so I will change to something like Bonecp (which wasrecommended) at a later date.

Comment: So what I'm asking is, does that have any affect on the connection not closing/reference files not being deleted?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It might be useful debugging. Put a breakpoint in the UcanaccessConnection.close method to see if it's  ever called and in UCanAccessDriver.connect to see how many connections are created.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorant question, but where exactly are these methods located?

Since I am using JPA the code above is how I connect.

I call I close both the entity manager and the factory.

                        em2.close();
                        emf2.close();
 
   System.out.println("Done");


[EL Info]: connection: 2014-10-14 16:45:42.751--ServerSession(1627258391)--file:.../build/classes/_AccessPU_transactionType=RESOURCE_LOCAL_url=jdbc:ucanaccess://...\samples\ice_cream.mdb;memory=false logout successful
Done

Not too sure what's going on... Sorry to be breaking everything :).

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'm having a bad time. I meant that you should debug the ucanaccess sources. If you can't, I'll try to reproduce your environment. Please let me know your findings.

Comment: No worries, I thought I might have scared you off :P.  Idk what you mean by having a "bad time" but if you're having some personal issues then good luck with that.

The reference files should be deleted, and according to my post above I am logging out of my Entity Connection.  So does this mean the reference files are there for another reason, or am I still logged in?

Has there been examples done with JPA and UCanAccess, I'm wondering if that's the issue.

Also if I turn this to memory=true will this just not matter anymore? Or it will matter since I'm still logged in?

Thanks

Comment: From the testing I've done I log into the db, and then log out, then log into another db, then log out, etc, etc, etc.  I don't have any issues connecting, but I do create a new reference file for each connection.

I was told to close both the entity manager and emfactory, which I do, so I wonder if there is somethigj I'm missing...? :(

Comment: I've been  a bit busy, neither personal issues nor fears.
Yes, specific reference files should be created for each  accdb/mdb file.
With the setting SingleConnection=true, if they aren't deleted at the resources closing, it means that  you're still logged in and, in other words, that there are one or more  ucanaccess connections still opened. So probably there is something to do with your EclipseLink configuration. I'll check it asap.

Comment: I haven't used "singelconnection=true" I'm assuming that goes after 

RESOURCE_LOCAL_url=jdbc:ucanaccess://...\samples\ice_cream.mdb;singleconnection=true???

I don't know why there would be more than one connection being created, weird I will have to take a look.

The eclipseLink info as in the actual jar or are you asking me for my persistence.xml?

I am still using memory=false and all, i haven't changed my config yet until we figure about this login issue.

Comment: Ok, this point has been lost. Basically you've to try jdbc:ucanaccess://...\samples\ice_cream.mdb;singleconnection=‌​true;memory=false, and see if reference files are deleted after closing the connections. If so, it's all ok. If not, I have to figure out why(I will do my own configuration). Please let me know your findings.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks, sorry I'm complicated with new stuff haha...  Very complicated with bugs... :)
  Will report findings!

Comment: So far it seems like it is still creating reference files when I add singleconnection=true.  I will look around and see what's going on, but I should be logging out.

Comment: Not too sure if you can see this, but I still think there is an issue, hopefully we can figure it out!!  so far memory=true is working great for me, but I figure the memory=false issue should be resolved.

Comment: I can see there might be an issue that I wasn't able to reproduce it.
May you share someway something more specific  (a source java, library list in your classpath, a simple junit test case), to help me?

Comment: Yes, no problem.  If you could give me a little time to get things settled i'll try to get it to you asap.  Thanks again for all of the help, and hopefully I can help reproduce this for you.

I seem to always find weird bugs no one can reproduce... :p.